# hive doesn't see partitions

Tags: sql, hive

I have a partitioned by `time key` table. When I try to select some rows

```
SELECT *
FROM agg
where time_key = '2017-04-09'
limit 10
```

I get nothing. When I replace `'2017-04-09'` with `'2017-04-23'`. Everything works. A few days ago, I accidentaly dropped this table and then restored it from trash. After I added some data so `'2017-04-23'` partition is new. Is this why select doesn't work as it should? How can I correct this?

[image]

Comment: The simplest conclusion is that no rows exist with that time key.

Comment: @Gor I checked the table directory. There is a folder `time_key=2017-04-09` which holds data.

Comment: `show partitions agg`. Check if you have defined all the relevant partitions

Comment: @Dudu I only get dates from 2017-04-19 to 2017-04-23

Comment: `msck repair table agg`

Comment: @Dudu `Malformed ORC file path/time_key=2016-09-29/000000_0. Invalid postscript` The old table was in textfile format and the new one in orc format. Now I see partitions, but can't do any select)) Doing alter table set fileformat didn't help. I think I'll need to reload the whole table somehow((

Comment: This is getting too messy. I have no idea what you are doing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have to fix this I will create two separate tables one with ORC and another with text format. Manually copy the partition folders to each of these tables based on the format. Run MSCK command to repair the tables. Then Insert data to one of the above table from another using a hive SQL.

Comment: That's what I did.